# NODE.js - How to make an AJAX request from the DOMContentLoaded listener

Tags: ajax

I am trying to send data via an Ajax request from the DOMContentLoaded listener in my global.js

The following code produces error 400 (Bad request), and I'm not clear why. If I submit the same payload using Postman to that Url, I get success.

**Global.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var obj1 = document.getElementById('myObject');

  // A bunch of logic to retrieve data to be sent to the server
  // that if successful triggers a callback function
     ProcessEvent: function (info){

//        Update the database record here
//
          alert("Making an AJAX call");
          var xcall = $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/cashiers/jsonset",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: obj1.items,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
              alert('Success : '+ json.reponse);
            },
            error: function(res){
              alert("Error "+res.status+" with "+res.statusText);
            }
          }).done(function( msg ){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
     }

});
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?  Errors?  Wrong result?  `DOMContentLoaded` not triggered?  Did you put error handlers on your ajax call to see if it was getting errors?  The PATCH verb will require successful pre-flight (with an OPTIONS request) before it will be allowed.  Is the target server allowing and supporting the pre-flight?  What is the URL of the webpage that this runs from?  Is it also `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: This doesn't seems to be nodejs related query, at best it can call a rest api which is hosted on nodejs but that is a separate concern. This is more of a frontend related issue hence removed the nodejs tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 The ajax call doesn't succeed. And yes, everything runs off the same local dev server at this point in time, so instead of "http://127.0.0.1:3000/cashiers/jsonset" I could've just specified "/cashiers/jsonset". I've also tried submitting it as a POST request with the same results (no call attempt is displayed in the npm console)

Comment: So, what is the Ajax error code that comes back?  You need to instrument to log the error.

Comment: Are you really expecting a `"script"` as the returned `dataType` from a PATCH operation?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: @jfriend00 with the extra messaging above the alert before making the call fires as expected, but neither success or error ones produce any alerts. I've modified the dataType to "json", but that didn't change the outcome. Same applies to substituting PATCH with POST.

Comment: Please don't use `alert()` to track down problems.  Because it's blocking until you dismiss the alert (e.g. stops the JS interpreter), it can mess with the timing of things.  Use `console.log()` instead and view the results in the debug console.  Also, you should check the console for other errors that might be displayed there.  Without a reproducible situation for this that we can debug outselves, it's unlikely we can do anything other than make wild guesses.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question: error code 400, however, I can submit the same json successfully using Postman

Comment: Well, the host doesn't like something in your jQuery version.  I'd suggest examining the two requests to see exactly what is different between what your jQuery code sends and what Postman sends.  FYI, I don't know if this matters, but http methods are usually all uppercase as in "POST".

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to manually do `data: JSON.stringify(obj1.items)` to get JSON as the content of the POST.  If you compare the two requests, that would also tell you.